# Annotation @Transactional not work in spring

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-transactions

To avoid deadlock, I want to update a list of ids row-by-row. To rollback data in spring, i am using annotation Transactional. But when i test the transaction, when an update sql throws an exception, it didn't rollback the data from the record that be updated before. Here is my code:

```
@Service
public class YahooBudgetUpdateService {
    @Autowired
    private AccounttUpdateMapper mapper; 
    
    public void accountUpdate() throws Exception {
       List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
       ids.add("1"); 
       ids.add("2"); 
       ids.add("3"); 
       updateAcnt(ids);
    }

    @Transactional 
    public void updateAcnt(List<String> ids) throw Exception {
        for(int i=0; i<ids.size; i++){
            updateById(ids.get(i));  
        }    
    }
}
```

Mapper.java:

```
public interface AccountUpdateMapper {
     int updateById(String id);
}
```

Mapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" 
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="src.mapper.AccountUpdateMapper">
<update id="updateById">
    UPDATE ad_cpnt
    SET
        updatedOn = now(),
        lst_updtd_dt= now(),
    where
        id = #{id}
</update>
</mapper>
```

I tried to use @Transactional(rollbackFor= {Exception.class}) but it didn't work, too. Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Is the `updateById` method marked @Transactional as well?

Comment: updateById is using xml to run sql (mybatis), so it is not marked @Transactional.

Comment: Is the table actually an InnoDB table that supports transactions?

Comment: @danblack yep, my table's engine is innoDB

Comment: Without seeing how the `updateAcnt` method is being called this question isn't going to be answered. The same for the `updateById` method without seeing how that works this is not going to be answered. You state you are using MyBatis, make sure that is setup properly with Spring else the transaction won't propagate and you have multiple standalone transactions.

Comment: @M.Deinum i edited my post. Can you check it?

Comment: You are calling the method interally, which means `@Transactionally` is useless. Either make the `accountUpdate` transactional or move the `updateAcnt` to another class which you inject and call.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried to make the accountUpdate transactional, remove transactional in updateAcnt, but it seemed not working :((

Comment: If you are calling that method internally as well that won't work either. All in all there is an incomplete picture here leading to guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is everything that will work

```
Service
public class YahooBudgetUpdateService {
    @Autowired
    private AccounttUpdateMapper mapper; 
    
    @Transactional  <-----This belongs here as it will not work with internal calls as explained in comments
    public void accountUpdate() throws Exception {
       List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
       ids.add("1"); 
       ids.add("2"); 
       ids.add("3"); 
       updateAcnt(ids);
    }

    public void updateAcnt(List<String> ids) throw Exception {
        for(int i=0; i<ids.size; i++){
            mapper.updateById(ids.get(i));  <-----here you must invoke it from mapper instance not another internal call
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: I called accountUpdate() from anther service that autowired YahooBudgetUpdateService.
And with updateById() i also invoked from mapper. But it did not rollback

Comment: did you caught the exception in a catch block?

Comment: I am using throws Exception so i think it don't need catch the exception. 
For testing, I am making an exception with id=2 when update account table. 
I checked the log and it showed the content of exception, and my app is not be interrupted

Comment: I doubt that, add to your question the testing code with the exception and also the stack trace that you see